# How to restart rsyslog daemon on ubuntu

Tags: rsyslog

how can i restart rsyslog or rsyslogd on ubuntu 10

```
root@terminator:/etc/init.d# service rsyslog status
rsyslog stop/waiting
root@terminator:/etc/init.d# service rsyslog stop
stop: Unknown instance:
root@terminator:/etc/init.d# service rsyslog restart
restart: Unknown instance:
root@terminator:/etc/init.d# service rsyslog start
start: Job failed to start
root@terminator:/etc/init.d# service rsyslogd start
rsyslogd: unrecognized service
```

Comment: Debugging info: http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/troubleshoot.html

Answer (score 122, accepted):

`sudo service rsyslog restart`

That should do it.

Comment: the output is shown above in the post

Comment: Have you modified the rsyslog.conf? If the config file is somehow invalid, service command cannot bring up the rsyslog.

Comment: Why would restart work with sudo, if it didn't work before as user root?

Answer (score 9):

If you are using systemctl, you can use:

```sh
systemctl restart rsyslog.service
```

Once restarted, check its status with the command:

```sh
systemctl status rsyslog.service
```